# Regular partial tilting modules in wild hereditary algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, wild-representation-type

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $Q$ be a connected wild quiver. Let $\mathcal{R}_1$, $\mathcal{R}_2$ be two regular components of the Auslander-Reiten quiver of $kQ$ that contain stones. When is it true that there exists quasi-simple stones $M\in\mathcal{R}_1$ and $N\in\mathcal{R}_2$ such that $Ext^1(M,N)=Ext^1(N,M)=0$ ?

Using Auslander-Reiten formula and the fact that the modules we care about are regular this problem is essentially a problem about $Hom$ between regular components. We know that there are $card(k)$ many regular components due to (XVIII.1.8) in [Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521708761). We further know that maps between regular components always exist in the wild hereditary case due to (XVIII.2.6) of the same book. Due to Lemma 1.4 in [Kerner, 1991](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002186939190215T) we can further reduce this problem to a problem about quasi-simples alone. However when do such maps occasionally not exist between some quasi-simples seem to either be an open question or be some existing result I'm currently unaware of. May I ask whether anyone has done any work on this problem?